# Why is it important to do the nitrosation of aniline to diazonium salts at low temperatures (0-5°C)?

Tags: organic-chemistry

The reaction the formation of diazonium salts starting from aniline (nitrosation of aniline), which should be performed at low temperature.

Comment: Diazonium salts are unstable and decompose readily at higher temperatures, sometimes explosively

Comment: If you work at higher temperatures, it's an expensive way to produce phenol.

Comment: The diazonium salt solution contains the ion $\ce{C_6H_5NN^+}$. At room temperature it is decomposed into phenol $\ce{C_6H_5OH}$ according to the equation $$\ce{C_6H_5NN^+ + 2 H_2O -> C_6H_5OH + N_2 + H_3O^+}$$